# HTTP headers for jpg files after mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, header, jpeg

I'm using Apache's `mod_rewrite` to route requests for JPG files to a directory outside my web root.

It generally has been fine, but there are a few images that do not display. I then realized that when I use PHP's `get_headers()` function on my image URLs, they are all returning
`Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8` instead of the proper `image/jpeg` header types.

I have tried explicitly setting the `Content-Type: image/jpeg` header and still, none of my images return the correct headers - although most do display correctly, but I'm not sure why.

How can I assure a JPG file is sent with the correct header when redirecting via `mod_rewrite`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is what you could do. Create a PHP file that will get the right file and passes it through

```
<?php 
$sImage = 'imagename.jpg';
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
header("Content-Length: " .(string)(filesize($sImage)) );

echo file_get_contents($sImage);
```

or

```
<?php
$sImage = 'imagename.jpg';
$rFP = fopen($sImage, 'rb');

header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
header("Content-Length: " .(string)(filesize($sImage)) );

fpassthru($rFP);
exit;
```

or in your Apache vhost config or .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule … … [T=image/jpeg]
```

Comment: `fpassthru()` is a better option, you don't need to load the whole file into memory.

Comment: Thanks, I did wind up specifying the headers using PHP with the fpassthru function.

Answer (score 9):

You can also set the *Content-Type* header field with mod_rewrite with the `T` flag:

```
RewriteRule … … [T=image/jpeg]
```

Answer (score 0):

> How about image which is not.jpg. Like .gif, ...

You'll need to use [mime_content_type()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) (which is deprecated) or the [fileinfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php) extension to determine which content-type to send.

Edit: I don't recommend this, but if you are working with a specific subset of file extensions, you could also create a small dictionary array of content-types and use the file extension to determine which one to send.